# How to generate code-mixed Hindi-English tweets using tweepy?

Tags: tweepy, hindi

I want extract tweets using tweepy which are in Romanagiri script or Hinglish Script. For example "#BMCelection vyapariyo se ek appeal #notebandi ka jawab abhi nahi to kabhi nahi. Vote for congress vote for progress @sanjaynirupam ". How can I extract such kind of tweets?